# Hovering over menu and sub menu

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical menu some of which have sub menu displayed to the right side. When I hover first menu and sub menus of it, it displays the second set of sub menu belonging to third menu.

```
<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Population and Socio-Economic Atlas</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="chapter1">Population</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" class="map11">Population Density</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="map12">Population By Sex</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="map13">Population By Age</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="chapter2">Education</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="chapter3">Agriculture</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" class="map31">Agricultural Land</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="map31">Agriculture Holding</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="map31">Agriculture By Type</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Level1 Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CA Election 2070</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="election1">Districts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="election2">Constituencies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="election3">Result</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" class="election31">District Map</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="election32">Constituencies Map</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" class="election33">Election Result 2070</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">To Be Continued</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

my CSS below:

```
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu {
    height: 250px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #FFCC99;
}
.menu li {
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    text-align:left;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin: 3px 0px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #393942;
}

.menu li a {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.menu li:hover > a { color: #FF0000; }

/* second level menu */
.menu ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    top: -26px;
    left: 295px;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }
.menu ul li {
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin: 6px 0px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}
.menu li:hover > ul li {
    height: 25px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0 0px;
}

.menu ul li a {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }

/* third level menu */
.menu ul ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    top: -26px;
    left: 195px;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #00FF00;
}
.menu ul ul:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }
.menu ul ul li {
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin: 6px 0px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0000FF;
}
.menu ul ul ul:hover > ul {
    height: 25px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0 0px;
}

.menu ul ul li a {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.menu ul li:last-child a { border: none; }
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please try to explain such problems with jsbin.com. People are more than happy to help if they understand the problem

Comment: Or JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hi, can you describe you problem in detail, I test your code on jsfiddle and I think it works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `display: block/none;` instead of `overflow: hidden/visible` to hide/unhide your sub-menus.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/3dAJw/)

`overflow` only affects visibility of the element. The element still exists in the DOM and responds to/ triggers all events associated with it. Hence, the issue.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if the solution helped you solve your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you use `opacity` to hide sub menus. When `opacity` is 0 then sub menu is still on page, and receives mouse events. Submenus added to lower elements, are higher in visibility stack, and that reason why they steal `hover`. Instead of `opacity` use `display`.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mL3eD/

Comment: Your suggestion helped me solve the problem. Help acknowledged.